# Why do these two fc api act differently?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was implementing the resnet and training on cifar-10 dataset. After "global average pooling" layer, I add 10-way fully connected layer. I used two tensorflow API to implement fc layer. However, the method 2 works to me, but the method 1 doesn't work. The method 1 is according to tensorflow official api: [tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected). The second method is according to [tf.layers.dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dense). I'm so confused why the first method doesn't work here. FYI, the output of global average pooling layer is [batch_size, 1, 1, 64]. Looking for some help! Thanks in advance!

Edit: Doesn't work means if I use the first method, all output logit of fc become zero, which doesn't make any sense to me.

```
# Method 1: 
def fc(x, n_outputs, scope):
  with tf.variable_scope(scope):
    # x = tf.layers.flatten(x)
    x = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(x, num_outputs=n_outputs, weights_initializer=weight_init, weights_regularizer=weight_reg, scope=scope)
    return x

# Method 2:
def fc(x, n_outputs, scope):
  with tf.variable_scope(scope):
     x = tf.layers.flatten(x)
     x = tf.layers.dense(x, units=n_outputs, kernel_initializer=weight_init, kernel_regularizer=weight_reg)
     return x
```

Comment: According to the official api document, tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected() have done flatten operation prior to the initial matrix multiply the weights. So we do not need flatten here.

Comment: Maybe you could specify what you mean by "works" and "doesn't work".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Doesn't work means if I use the first method, all the output logits will be zero, which doesn't make any sense.